# Polymer - Conditional Template

Tags: polymer

I am learning Polymer. Right now, I am trying to conditionally display a template.

**my-component.html**

```
<dom-module id="my-component">
    <template>
      <h5>There are <span>[[ orders.length ]]</span> orders.</h5>
      <template is="dom-if" if="[[ orders.length > 0]]">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ orders }}" as="order">
          <div class="order-item">
            <span>[[ order.description ]]</span>
          </span>              
        </template>        
      </template>

      <template is="dom-if" if="[[ orders.length == 0]]">
        No orders have been placed
      </template>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "my-component",
            properties: {
              orders: Array
            }                    
        });
  </script> 
</dom-module>
```

My question is, how do I show one block of HTML if my array has items in it and another block of HTML if the array doesn't have any items? The `h5` tag is displaying the correct number of items. For that reason, I know my binding is setup properly. However, I do not know how to conditionally show a template.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymer doesn't support that kind of [expressions in binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#expressions-in-binding-annotations). Generally, if you want expressions, you need to use [computed bidings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) instead. In this specific case, because 0 evaluates to `false` and other values to `true` and you can do it like this:

```
  <template is="dom-if" if="[[ orders.length ]]">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ orders }}" as="order">
      <div class="order-item">
        <span>[[ order.description ]]</span>
      </div>              
    </template>        
  </template>

  <template is="dom-if" if="[[ !orders.length ]]">
    No orders have been placed
  </template>
```